# Make a model in Python using the Forward Euler scheme (FTCS)

Tags: python, matplotlib, numerical-methods

Solve the 1-dimensional advection equation `∂θ/dt = -c dθ/dx` by using centered differences in space and forward differences in time. Apply a periodic boundary condition `θ^(n)` *`(J) = θ^(n) (0)`. J = 100 and the initial condition is  θ^(0)*_j = f0(j), where

F0(j)=0, j = 1,...46

F0(47)=0.3

F0(48)=0.6

F0(49)=09

F0(50)= 1.2

F0(51) =0.9

F0(52)=0.6

F0(53)=0.3

F0(54-->)=0

c = 1 #wavenumber

∆*x = L/J = 1*

∆*t = 0.75 #timestep*

with this information, make a FTCS scheme model and integrate the model 20 time steps. Plot the solution (numerical and analytical) for the times t=0, and 4 ∆*t.*

```
c=1
J=100
L=100
dx=1
dt=0.75

Courant_number = (c*dt)/(2*dx)
F0_j = np.zeros((100,100)) #matrise

F0_j[47,0]=0.3
F0_j[48,0]=0.6
F0_j[49,0]=0.9
F0_j[50,0]=1.2
F0_j[51,0]=0.9
F0_j[52,0]=0.6
F0_j[53,0]=0.3

for j in range(J):
    for n in range(L):
        if n == 99:
            continue
        if j == 99:
            F0_j[j,n] = F0_j[0,n]
            continue
        F0_j[j,n+1] = F0_j[j,n]-(Courant_number*(F0_j[j+1,n]-F0_j[j-1,n]))

plt.plot(F0_j)
```

Comment: Do you have a very specific question?  Does your code solve the homework problem?  Or do you suspect something is wrong?  Could you add some more explanation why you want to post this here?

Comment: Yes! I suspect something is wrong with the plot that I've made here.. I am supposed to get a function/graph for every timeperiod (I think), but here I have everything in one plot..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

On the periodicity condition: With the central difference quotient you propagate the range `F0[1:-1,j]`. The outer elements need to be copied from the other end. The element `0` gets copied from place `J`, which is thus not the outer element, and the element `J+1` gets copied from place `1`. So

```
F0 = np.zeros((J+2,L+1))  # space, time
```

Explicit loops are slow, thus should be avoided. Especially as you are already using numpy.

```
for n in range(L):
    F0[1:-1,n+1] = F0[1:-1,n]-(Courant_number*(F0[2:,n]-F0_j[:-2,n]))
    F0[0,n+1], F0[-1,n+1] = F0[-2,n+1], F0[1,n+1]
```

You could also use the `np.roll` procedure to realize this without border cells, `C*( np.roll(F0[:,n],-1) - np.roll(F0[:,n],1) )`

---

To get a gallery of plots you need to generate each graph separately, either using subplots for a selection of graphs arranged in one figure, or generating multiple figures.

```
for k in range(11):
    plt.plot(F0[:,10*k], label=f"t={10*k}")
    plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```